# Can Notes.app undo?

Tags: macos, notes.app

I had some *very* critical data that I'd taken down from a meeting in a note inside of Notes.app.

I did the following:

- Select all
- hit key 'x' (meant to choose 'command-x')
- I went to another app, then came back and realized what had happened
- Attempted 'command-z' or 'File -> undo', to no avail

Devastated.
Does anyone know of a solution to this problem?
Is it possible that I might be able to restore my data somehow?

This happened within the span of an hour, and I don't have a time machine backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have another device logged in to your iCloud account to which the note originated which has the notes service activated and the original note stored, you may be able to get the note back by disabling the network and opening the note, copying out the data somewhere else. Apart from this, no, there is no way to recover past versions of a note.

Comment: absolutely ridiculous.  thanks for the clarification.